# Change congestion control algorithms per connection

Tags: linux, sysctl, congestion-control

The command 'sysctl' in linux as of now changes the congestion control algorithm globally for the entire system. But congestion control, where the TCP window size and other similar parameters are varied, are normally done per TCP connection. So my question is:

- Does there exist a way where I can change the congestion control algorithm being used per TCP connection?

Or am I missing something trivial here? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 6):

This is done in [iperf](http://iperf.sourceforge.net/) using the -Z option - the patch is [here](http://iperf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/iperf/trunk/src/PerfSocket.cpp?revision=25&view=markup).

This is how it is implemented (PerfSocket.cpp, line 93) :

```
    if ( isCongestionControl( inSettings ) ) {
#ifdef TCP_CONGESTION
    Socklen_t len = strlen( inSettings->mCongestion ) + 1;
    int rc = setsockopt( inSettings->mSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CONGESTION,
                 inSettings->mCongestion, len);
    if (rc == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Attempt to set '%s' congestion control failed: %s\n",
            inSettings->mCongestion, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
#else
    fprintf( stderr, "The -Z option is not available on this operating system\n");
#endif
```

Where **mCongestion** is a string containing the name of the algorithm to use

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is possible via get/setsockopt. The only documentation i found is:
http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/net/0811.2/00020.html

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Linux it is possible to set the congestion control for a specific destination using ip route ... congctl .

If anyone are familiar with this approach, please edit this post.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to change default TCP congestion control per process (I'd love bash script being able to say that whatever is executed by this script should default the congestion control `lp`).

The only user mode API I'm aware of is as follows:

```
setsockopt(socket, SOL_TCP, TCP_CONGESTION, congestion_alg, strlen(congestion_alg));
```

where `socket` is an open socket, and `congestion_alg` is a string containing one of the words in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_allowed_congestion_control`.

Answer (score -1):

Linux has [pluggable congestion algorithms](http://linuxgazette.net/135/pfeiffer.html) which can change the algorithm used on the fly but this is a system wide setting not per connection.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that.
"$ sudo modprobe tcp_<congestion_algorithm>"
will add the specified algorithm as an entry in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control.

But my question is about connection-specific settings.

Comment: Well thats not per connection, that would be slow to look up for each connection.

Comment: The default setting is in /proc/.../tcp_congestion_control. The algorithms selectable via setsockopt are in tcp_available_congestion_control. There's another file which contains all the algorithms installed in the kernel. However mixing different congestion control algorithms on the same device will usually result in one stealing most of the bandwidth (reno almost always loses out)